# gl_SubgroupInvocationID numeration in multi-dimensional work-groups

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

Regarding [GL_KHR_shader_subgroup](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_shader_subgroup.txt) extension and compute shader... `gl_SubgroupInvocationID` is 1-dimensional (single `uint`) while work-groups are can be up to 3-dimensional. So I'm wondering which 3-dimensional numbers of `gl_LocalInvocationID` (threads within work-group) get to be in each subgroup.
For example: let's say I have work-group 16x16x1 and `gl_SubgroupSize` is 32. How can I tell which threads of current work-group are in subgroup 0 (`gl_SubgroupInvocationID == 0`)?

Answer (score 2):

The partitioning of a workgroup into subgroups is implementation defined. Furthermore, you're not supposed to care about it.

The purpose of the subgroup functions is to facilitate intercommunication between subgroups. To ask about values computed in other subgroups relative to your invocation. The only functions that care about a specific "physical" relationship between subgroups are the `Quad` functions, which deal with operations on 2x2 blocks within fragment shaders.

Comment: Not quite. The `Clustered` functions (e.g. `subgroupClusteredAdd`) also very much care about the relationship between subgroups. They even have an example in https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-subgroup-tutorial, but unfortunately it doesn't give much details.